# Azure Event Hubs - Geo-Recovery: can we disable the automatic failover?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, geo-replication

I have an Azure Event Hubs in WEST US with **Geo-Recovery** enabled to sync with EAST US. I don't want to automatically failover to EAST US in case of the Primary outage, can we disable the automatic failover? I want to manually do the failover post business confirmation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Event Hubs - Geo-Recovery: does it replicate to the Secondary region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213745/azure-event-hubs-geo-recovery-does-it-replicate-to-the-secondary-region)

Comment: There is no automatic-failover feature provided by EH service. Are you referring to some other service doing health check on EH endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic failover from Microsoft end when you have set up the Geo-disaster recovery for the event hub. You need to manually do the failover either from azure portal/REST API's. The failover can also be automated based on your business scenario where your custom application will monitor the resource and based on your business conditions your custom application will be calling the event hub REST endpoint to initiate the failover.