# Azure Event Hubs Geo-Recovery: what will happen to the unread data is on the primary region during the failover?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, geo-replication

I have an Azure Event Hubs in **WEST US** with Geo-Recovery enabled to sync with **EAST US**. As per the Microsoft article -

> The feature enables instant continuity of operations with the same
> configuration, but doesn't replicate the messages held in queues or
> topic subscriptions or dead-letter queues.

In case of a manual failover, is there way to copy the data from the Primary region to secondary region that is not yet consumed? if not, any reason why the unread data can be copied over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Event Hubs - Geo-Recovery: does it replicate to the Secondary region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213745/azure-event-hubs-geo-recovery-does-it-replicate-to-the-secondary-region)

Answer (score 1):

Event Hub Geo-disaster is only for metadata disaster recovery and not for events in event hub disaster recovery. Geo-disaster is mainly used in the scenario when you don't want to update the connection string in your different applications in case of disaster and saves your time creating the new namespace with all the event hub/configurations and updating the new connection string.