# Programmatically initiate Event hub failover

Tags: azure-eventhub, failover, disaster-recovery

Answer for this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222516/azure-event-hubs-geo-recovery-what-will-happen-to-the-unread-data-is-on-the-pri/66331597#66331597) says event hub REST end points can be used to initiate the fail over, but I don't find any Microsoft docs about event hub REST end points.
Could you please share how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read this doc [Azure Event Hubs - Geo-disaster recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-geo-dr) for the concept if you need it.

For `rest api`, please refer to this official doc: [Disaster Recovery Configs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/stable/disasterrecoveryconfigs).

For `java`, you can refer to this sample in github: [eventhub-java-manage-event-hub-geo-disaster-recovery](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/eventhub-java-manage-event-hub-geo-disaster-recovery).

For `.net`, you can refer to this sample in github: [Microsoft Azure Event Hubs Geo-DR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/samples/Management/DotNet/GeoDRClient).

Comment: once the fail over happens, does the client need to update connection strings in their config?

Comment: @user1229441,Yes.  Actually, once you configure Geo-disaster recovery, you should use this  `primary connection string for the alias` in your config. Please follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-geo-dr#setup)(in step 7) for how to get the `primary connection string for the alias`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong about the below statement.
Secondary namespace and alias are created before hand and when the fail over is initiated secondary namespace will start receiving events.